# Saving user information in wpf c# app

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a c# wpf application that will store users information and allow users to view other users profiles in a corporation.

What would be the best way to store the data that each user is entering in order to have it accessible from a centralized location?

I'm fairly new to creating connections to databases in wpf applications and any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I've been reading a bit about SQLlite and it seems like it has its pros due to its mobile characteristics but does this mean that the SQLlite database will be local to each user? I need it to be centralized so that data entered from anywhere goes into one database.

Thank you

Comment: Depends entirely on the environment and infrastructure in place. Your question implies that the application is going to be deployed to a controlled environment. You'll need a centrally accessible data store. Does SQLlite allow each user to connect remotely to a single instance of it?

Comment: Agree with above comment. The common way to do this is to run a server to save information. You can choose to persist incoming data anyway you like (SQLite included but why not full fledged dbms?) You client keep feeding to the server.

Comment: For your last concern about SQLLite, you are correct. SQLLite is not indicated for your situation. You need a database server that can accommodate multiple client connections. SQLLite does not do this. It's simply a wrapper around a local data store. If you tried using this, each instance of your application would have its own database that wouldn't communicate with each other.

Comment: Thanks to all of your for your prompt responses! I will most probably be going with sql server, creating a centralized connection in the app config, and reading more about to ensure it is the most scalable solution for what I need. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use ADO.net datasets to get the data from the server but this is done by downloading a local datatable and syncing it using a data adapter

[connection between client and server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ12e.png)

[how to do in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCSiz.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you stated mobile characteristics are not what you need.  As for a central database consider the free SQL Express from Microsoft.  You will need some type of security so they can only update their own profile.

Comment: I think I'm going to go ahead and download SQL as I have a student account that permits me to download the software free of charge and test it and configure it with that. I guess that when it gets implemented in the organization I would just connect to their SQL and run a couple of queries that will create the database and tables needed and then configure the connection. I'm just trying to make this as scalable as possible considering its my first project. Thank you so much!

Comment: SQL Express is probably more than enough for users information.  But the full version would not hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the more straightforward options is to create an Entity Framework model for your application. This may serve as a primer for your exploration of the topic:

[Databinding with WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx)

You'll probably find it easiest to develop against your local SQLExpress instance or some other local data store. But the final solution will need to be connected to an enterprise-ready database. Since there was no mention of cost constraints and the nature of this question is more of "how?" versus "what to use?", I see no reason why this shouldn't be a SQL Server solution.

Ultimately, though, this question is rather broad in scope and cannot be adequately addressed in a simple answer here.

Comment: The first organization that I will implement this on has an existing SQL server infrastructure. I will more than likely leverage this and lay a database on it in which this application will run off. Thank you for your help!